# Hide and show html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a wordpress site. I am new in this and here is what i have achieved so far. I am trying to hide and show the content on page scroll and, i have tried doing it using javascript. I don't know if there is a better way to do it. This code is working fine when scrolling from top to bottom, but not well from bottom to top. It skips the content. Thankyou

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $('#slide-twotitle').hide();
 $('#slide-threetitle').hide();
 $('#slide-fourtitle').hide();
 $('.slide-fivetitle').hide();

 $(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 300) {
  $('#slide-onetitle').show();
 
 } else {
 $('#slide-onetitle').hide();
  
 }
if (scroll > 300 && scroll <800 ) {
  $('#slide-twotitle').show();
 
 } else {
 $('#slide-twotitle').hide();
  
 } 
  if (scroll > 800 && scroll <1400 ) {
  $('#slide-threetitle').show();
 
 } else {
 $('#slide-threetitle').hide();
  
 }
   if (scroll > 1400 && scroll <2000 ) {
  $('#slide-fourtitle').show();
 
 } else {
 $('.slide-fourtitle').hide();
  
 }
   if (scroll > 2000 && scroll <2600 ) {
  $('.slide-fivetitle').show();
 
 } else {
 $('.slide-fivetitle').hide();
  
 }
 });
})
</script>
```

```html
<a href="#one" class="hash"  id="slide-one"></a>
<div class="swiper-container swiper1">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/PlatoonTexture.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p style="font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 200px;">We completed the London headquarters for music startup Platoon, responding to the Kings Cross site’s small footprint of 1900 sq. feet with an adaptable yet intimate arrangement of spaces. 

Using a contrasting palette of black-blues, off-whites and pale pink with starker black graphic elements and zoned lighting, we wanted to create a loft apartment-like feel in a workplace that regularly welcomes both new and established recording artists.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon3.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon4.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon5.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="project-title" id="slide-onetitle" style="text-align: center;">PLATOON HQ KING'S CROSS LONDON 1</h1>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->

     <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <a href="#slide-two" class="down-arrow"><img src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/arrow-down-white.png"></a>
  </div>
  
<a href="#two" class="hash" id="slide-two"></a>
  <div class="swiper-container swiper1 hash" id="2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/PlatoonTexture.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p style="font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 200px;">We completed the London headquarters for music startup Platoon, responding to the Kings Cross site’s small footprint of 1900 sq. feet with an adaptable yet intimate arrangement of spaces. 

Using a contrasting palette of black-blues, off-whites and pale pink with starker black graphic elements and zoned lighting, we wanted to create a loft apartment-like feel in a workplace that regularly welcomes both new and established recording artists.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon3.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="project-title" id="slide-twotitle" style="text-align: center;">PLATOON HQ KING'S CROSS LONDON 2</h1>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->

     <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <a href="#slide-three" class="down-arrow"><img src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/arrow-down-white.png"></a>
  </div>

<a href="#three" class="hash" id="slide-three"></a>
  <div class="swiper-container swiper1 hash" id="2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/PlatoonTexture.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p style="font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 200px;">We completed the London headquarters for music startup Platoon, responding to the Kings Cross site’s small footprint of 1900 sq. feet with an adaptable yet intimate arrangement of spaces. 

Using a contrasting palette of black-blues, off-whites and pale pink with starker black graphic elements and zoned lighting, we wanted to create a loft apartment-like feel in a workplace that regularly welcomes both new and established recording artists.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon3.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="project-title" id="slide-threetitle" style="text-align: center;">PLATOON HQ KING'S CROSS LONDON 3</h1>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->

     <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <a href="#slide-four" class="down-arrow"><img src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/arrow-down-white.png"></a>
  </div>

<a href="#four" class="hash" id="slide-four"></a>
  <div class="swiper-container swiper1 hash" id="2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/PlatoonTexture.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p style="font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 200px;">We completed the London headquarters for music startup Platoon, responding to the Kings Cross site’s small footprint of 1900 sq. feet with an adaptable yet intimate arrangement of spaces. 

Using a contrasting palette of black-blues, off-whites and pale pink with starker black graphic elements and zoned lighting, we wanted to create a loft apartment-like feel in a workplace that regularly welcomes both new and established recording artists.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="project-title" id="slide-fourtitle" style="text-align: center;">PLATOON HQ KING'S CROSS LONDON 4</h1>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->

     <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <a href="#slide-five" class="down-arrow"><img src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/arrow-down-white.png"></a>
  </div>

<a href="#five" class="hash" id="slide-five"></a>
  <div class="swiper-container swiper1 hash" id="2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/PlatoonTexture.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p style="font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 200px;">We completed the London headquarters for music startup Platoon, responding to the Kings Cross site’s small footprint of 1900 sq. feet with an adaptable yet intimate arrangement of spaces. 

Using a contrasting palette of black-blues, off-whites and pale pink with starker black graphic elements and zoned lighting, we wanted to create a loft apartment-like feel in a workplace that regularly welcomes both new and established recording artists.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="http://studio-party.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Divi/slider/Platoon2.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="project-title slide-fivetitle" style="text-align: center;">PLATOON HQ KING'S CROSS LONDON 5</h1>
   
   
   
  
    <!-- Add Pagination -->

     <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't bother rolling your own lazy loader. Just use one that is already battle tested:
http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/

This will load based on content rather than scrollbar position.

This is important because the content visible based on scrollbar position will change depending on the height and width of the viewport. So, you want it to load based on content position rather than scrollbar position.

Comment: can you please tell me how i can i use it on my above code, Thankyou

Comment: Well, it looks like you are already importing and using jQuery, so your part way there. You can nix all of your lazy loader logic you have there and instead, import the plugin below your jQuery import and follow the documentation on how to instantiate the lazy loader and implement it. The page I linked has the instructions if you scroll down a bit.

Comment: Do i need to add lazy class here,<h1 class="project-title" id="slide-onetitle" style="text-align: center;">PLATOON HQ KING'S CROSS LONDON 1</h1>?

Comment: Yes. You will add the .lazy class to any elements on your page that you want the plugin to control. The plugin will determine for you when to display the content - and you can use the threshold property to adjust the offset (how far you have to scroll) before the content appears.

Comment: Can you please add a little code just a sample?

Answer (score 0):

My honest opinion is that if you are keen on writing code, specifically javascript, Wordpress may not be the way to go. It is a CMS mostly aimed at people with no intention to write code.

I cannot help you better than invite you to try out something like [React](https://reactjs.org/) where all these problems you are taking on head-first will be solved for you.